# Why can't I reference a (particular) Perl array as I'd expect?

Tags: perl

I am attempting to use the following to iterate through an array of arrays:

```
foreach my $elem ( @{ $mastermap } )
{
    say $elem;
    say $elem[0];
    say Dumper($elem);
}
```

(All just debug output at this point, not what I actually want to do with the array data.)
The output I'm getting (repeated for each loop iteration) is something like:

```
ARRAY(0x55dabc740cc0)
Use of uninitialized value in say at test.pl line 39.

$VAR1 = [
          'bob',
          '*',
          '1492',
          '1492',
          'machine acct',
          '/var/bob',
          '/bin/false'
        ];
```

So $elem is an array (also tried treating it as a hash, which was wrong), and Dumper can output the contents of the array, but $elem[0] is undefined?  Please tell me what I'm misunderstanding about arrays (probably quite a bit).  In case it helps, $mastermap is (I think) an array of arrays, read in using Text::CSV as follows:

```
my $mastermap = csv ({ in => $passwd, sep_char => ":", quote_char => "#" });
```

where $passwd is more or less a copy of /etc/passwd.

Comment: Can you run `say @$elem; say ref($elem); say ref(@$elem);` and add the output of that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$elem[0]` tries to access to the 1st item in the array `@elem`. What you actually want to is to access the 1st item in the array reference `$elem`. The correct syntax to do so is:

```
$elem->[0]
```

or

```
$$elem[0]
```

---

You should always add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to the beginning of your Perl scripts/programs. Doing so would have produced the following warning:

```
Global symbol "@elem" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @elem"?) at...
```

Comment: Thanks; I swear I tried to use $elem->[0] previously but it yelled at me.  I am using warnings, but was not using strict.